Error with "update features" REST end request
When trying to use update feature request on one of our standalone server. The operation fails with two different errors.
On UAT

On PROD

Editing works in ArcGIS Pro, fails only through REST request.

People might be more willing to comment or answer if the error messages are in plain text instead of an image of the error message they might have to click on and zoom to read.

Cross-posted at Error with "update features" REST end request. - Esri Community

Overwriting the service resolved this issue.
